# Complement of codim 2 manifold is connected?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

If M is a connected n-manifold and N is a codim 2 submanifold
then M-N is connected.

Is this true?

I want to show $H_0(M-N)=\mathbb Z$. I think it's better to do in $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficient because we get orientability. But because no compactness is mentioned I can't use Poincare duality. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You probably want to assume that $N$ is a closed subset of $M$.

Comment: So, what are your thoughts about the answers? In particular, are you implicitly assuming that $N$ is a smooth submanifold of a smooth manifold and $N$ is closed as a subset?

Answer (score 6):

This has little to do with orientability, nor compactness, Poincare duality, nor $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients. It's just proving path connectivity of $M-N$. Also, the proof works in any codimension $q \ge 2$, and I'll write it that way.

Consider any $x,y \in M-N$.

Start by choosing a continuous path $\gamma : [0,1] \to M$ such that $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma(1)=y$. Of course the path $\gamma$ might hit $N$.

The intuition is that because $N$ is of codimension $q \ge 2$, when the path $\gamma$ comes close to $N$ you can push it away. The result is a path $\delta : [0,1] \to M-N$. The endpoints $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma(1)$ will be far enough away that they don't get moved when you push other portions of the path away from $N$, hence $\delta(0)=\gamma(0)$ and $\delta(1)=\gamma(1)$, and we obtain a path $\delta$ in $M-N$ from $x$ to $y$

To make this intuition work one applies the [Tubular Neighborhood Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_neighborhood) and the same [Lebesgue number lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma) techniques that are used elsewhere in algebraic topology.

Here are some details. The [Tubular Neighborhood Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_neighborhood) applied to the submanifold $N \subset M$ produces an open $U \subset M$ with $N \subset U$, and a continuous retract $f : U \to N$, such that $f$ is a [fiber bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle) in which the fibers are homeomorphic to the open q-dimensional disc $D^q$. Each $p \in N$ has a path connected open neighborhood $V_p \subset N$ and a homeomorphism $h_p : U_p = f^{-1}(V_p) \approx V_p \times D^q$ such that $h_p(U_p \cap N) = V_p \times \{0\}$. Because both $V_p$ and $D^q - \{0\}$ are path connected (this is where we use $q \ge 2$), it follows that $h_p(U_p - N) = V_p \times (D^q - \{0\})$ is path connected. Because $h_p$ is a homeomorphism, it follows that $U_p - N$ is path connected.

You can choose $U$ to be a subset of any prechosen open neighborhood of $N$; let's choose $U$ to be a subset of $M - \{x,y\}$.

Consider the following open covering of $M$:
$$\mathcal U = \{M-N\} \cup \{U_p \mid p \in N\}
$$
By pullback we get an open covering of $[0,1]$:
$$\gamma^{-1}(\mathcal U) = \{\gamma^{-1}(M-N)\} \cup \{\gamma^{-1}(U_p) \mid p \in N\}
$$
Applying the Lebesgue number lemma, we obtain a subdivision
$$0 = x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_K = 1
$$
such that for each $k=1,\ldots,K$ the restriction $\gamma[x_{k-1},x_k]$ has image contained in some element of the open covering $\gamma^{-1}(\mathcal U)$.

Using all this structure, let's construct a path $\delta : [0,1] \to M-N$ with $\delta(0)=x$, $\delta(1)=y$.

**Step 1:** If $\gamma(x_k) \not\in N$, let $\delta(x_k)=\gamma(x_k)$. And if $\gamma[x_{k-1},x_k]$ is disjoint from $N$, let $\delta(x)=\gamma(x)$ for all $x \in [x_{k-1},x_k]$. Note that this case applies whenever $\gamma[x_{k-1},x_k]$ contains a point that is not in $U$, because $M-N$ is the only element of the open cover $\mathcal U$ that has nonempty intersection with $M-U$. So, for example, $\delta$ equals $\gamma$ on the subintervals $[x_0,x_1]$ and $[x_{K-1},x_K]$.

**Step 2:** For any $x_k$, if $\gamma(x_k) \in N$ then choose $\delta(x_k)$ to be a point of $U_{\gamma(x_k)} - N$ such that $f(\delta(x_k)) = \gamma(x_k)$.

**Step 3:** For any $k=1,...,K$, if $\gamma[x_{k-1},x_k] \cap N \ne \emptyset$ then there exists $p \in N$ such that $\gamma[x_{k-1},x_k] \subset U_p$. In Steps 1 and 2 we have already found endpoint values $\delta(x_{k-1})$, $\delta(x_k)$ in $U_p - N$. Since $U_p - N$ is path connected, we can define $\delta$ on $[x_{k-1},x_k]$ with those endpoint values.

Comment: This proof (which require existence of a tubular neighborhood) works only if $N$ is a smooth submanifold or, more generally, a locally flat submanifold.

Comment: True enough. Perhaps the OP would comment on whether that was the intention.

Comment: The argument also requires the submanifold to be a closed subset of $M$. I am really unsure what happens it you drop this assumption.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an argument which works for a connected $n$-dimensional topological manifold $M$ and a closed subset $C\subset M$  homeomorphic to a manifold of dimension $\le n-2$. I am not sure what happens if you drop the assumption that $C$ is closed. My suspicion is that the complement need not be path-connected, but it might still be connected.

First of all, it suffices to work with oriented manifolds $M$ (otherwise, you work in the orientation cover of $M$). Next, using only the assumption that $C$ is a closed subset of $M$, a form of the Poincare-Lefschetz duality in this situation yields an isomorphism
$$ 
\check{H}^*_c(C)\cong H_{n-*}(M, M-C),
$$
where the left hand side is the Chech cohomology with compact support. For manifolds, Chech cohomology is isomorphic to the singular cohomology and, hence, the dimension assumption yields
$$
\check{H}^{n-1}_c(C)={H}^{n-1}_c(C)=0.
$$
Next, I will use the long exact sequence of the pair $(M, M-C)$:
$$
\to H_1(M)\to 0=H_1(M, M-C)\to \tilde{H}_0(M-C) \to \tilde{H}_0(M)=0
$$
Thus, $\tilde{H}_0(M-C)=0$ and, hence, $M-C$ is path-connected.

Comment: 1) I think this answer shows the assumption that $C$ is a manifold is unimportant if $C$ is assumed to be closed and instead to have given inductive dimension / given Lebesgue covering dimension $n-2$ or less (I think one just concludes immediately that $\check{H}^{n-1}_c(C) = 0$). 2) Would you please provide a reference for this form of Poincare-Lefschetz duality? By the way, thank you for another excellent answer.

Answer (score 2):

The goal of this answer is to use Moishe Kohan's idea to prove the general statement for not-necessarily-closed submanifolds. In fact even more than that can be said.

Let $M$ be a metrizable topological manifold and let $f: S \to M$ be a continuous injection from a second-countable topological manifold with $\dim S \leq \dim M - 2$. (Notice that this need not be an embedding. For instance, $f$ could be a map from $\Bbb Z^2$ with image $\Bbb Q^2 \subset M$.)

> Theorem: $M \setminus f(S)$ is path-connected. In fact, for any two points $x,y \in M \setminus f(S)$, and any continuous path $\gamma: [0,1] \to M$ with $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\gamma(1) = y$, there is an arbitrarily close continuous path with the same endpoints whose image is contained in $M \setminus S$.

*Remark.* Injectivity is necessary because of the existence of space-filling curves. Second-countability is necessary as otherwise one could take $S$ to be $M$ equipped with the discrete topology, and $f$ to be the canonical injection.

---

> Lemma: If $D$ is a closed disc embedded in $M$ of dimension $\dim D \leq \dim M - 2$ and $x, y \in M \setminus D$, write $\mathcal P_{x \to y} M$ for the space of continuous paths from $x$ to $y$ in $M$. Then $\mathcal P_{x \to y} (M \setminus D)$ is open and dense in $\mathcal P_{x \to y} M$.

Proof: because $S$ is closed in $M$, the set of paths with image in $M \setminus D$ is open in the compact-open topology (by definition).

Denseness is more difficult. Suppose $\gamma: [0,1] \to M$ is a continuous path with $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\gamma(1) = y$. Then $\gamma^{-1}(D)$ is a closed subset of $[0,1]$ not including the endpoints.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. We will construct a path $\eta$ with $d_\infty(\gamma, \eta) \leq \epsilon$ and $\eta^{-1}(D) = \varnothing$. Carrying out this construction for all $\eta$ proves the desired density result.

Using the Lebesgue number lemma, one may find $n$ large so that

$\gamma([i/n, (i+1)/n]$ has diameter less than $\epsilon/2$ for all $0 \leq i < n$.

Write $U_{\epsilon,i} \subset M$ for the open set of points $$\{x \in M \mid \text{sup}_{t \in [i/n, (i+1)/n]} d(\gamma(t), x) < \epsilon\}.$$

For each $0 < i < n$ pick $x_i \in U_{\epsilon,i} \setminus D$. This exists because otherwise $D$ would contain an open subset of $M$, contradicting its dimension and the invariance of domain theorem. Set $x_0 = x$ and $x_n = y$.

Using Moishe Kohan's result, for each $0 \leq i < n$ there exists a path $\eta_i: [i/n, (i+1)/n] \to U_{\epsilon, i} \setminus D$ with $\eta_i(i/n) = x_i$ and $\eta_i\left(\frac{i+1}{n}\right) = x_{i+1}$.

Notice that $d_\infty(\eta_i, \gamma|_{[i/n, (i+1)/n]}) < \epsilon.$

Now define $\eta(t)$ to be $\eta_i(t)$ whenever $i/n \leq t \leq (i+1)/n$. Notice that this gives a well-defined continuous path on all of $[0,1]$, with $$d_\infty(\eta, \gamma) < \epsilon,$$ and with $\eta$ missing $D$, as desired.

---

To prove the Theorem, write $S$ as the union of countably many closed discs $D_i$. Because the domain is compact and the codomain is Hausdorff, $f$ gives a homeomorphism of $D_i$ onto $f(D_i)$. We have already seen that $\mathcal P_{x \to y} [M \setminus f(D_i)]$ is dense in $\mathcal P_{x \to y} M$. But $$\mathcal P_{x \to y} [M \setminus f(S)] = \bigcap_i \mathcal P_{x \to y} [M \setminus f(D_i)].$$

This is an intersection of countably many open dense sets inside the complete metric space $\mathcal P_{x \to y} M$. Complete metric spaces are Baire, and hence this intersection is once again dense and in particular nonempty. The theorem follows.

Comment: Great!.........